# sqlalchemy automap adding primary key

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I have an oracle db containing like 1000 tables. I want to read from only 20 of the tables. I have used Automap extention & metadata to declare the table classes.

Problem is that some tables dont have a primary key.

```
from config import E3_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, MetaData, Column, String, Table
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base

engine = create_engine(E3_SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI)
metadata = MetaData()
# auto-map db tables, list down the tables you want to query here
metadata.reflect(engine, only=['table_name1',
                               'table_name2',
                               'table_name3']}
Base = automap_base(metadata=metadata)
Base.prepare()
# db declaration
Table1 = Base.classes.table_name2
Table2 = Base.classes.table_name1
Table3 = Base.classes.table_name3
# create sqlalchemy session
session = Session(engine)
```

This causes Atrtibute error since there is no primary key for table3

I am checking http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_0/faq/ormconfiguration.html#how-do-i-map-a-table-that-has-no-primary-key , and trying to add primary key without changing the db tables directly.

I am not sure how to do this. 
I tried to do this few ways. but all got errors. This is schema for table3 , no primary key is declared though.

[image]

```
class Table3(Base):
    __table__ = 'table_name3'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    # name = Column('name', String(1024), primary_key=True)
    # collection_key = Column('name', String(8192), primary_key=True)
    __mapper_args__ = {'primary_key': ['name', 'priority']}
```

I dont want to change the db table to add primary_key, instead want to handle within sqlalachemy. So I tried declaring primary key using **mapper_args** by using two exiting columns.

```
In [40]: e3.query(FD_Group)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-6793c4942672> in <module>()
----> 1 e3.query(FD_Group)

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\session.py in query(self, *entities
, **kwargs)
   1247         :class:`.Session`."""
   1248
-> 1249         return self._query_cls(entities, self, **kwargs)
   1250
   1251     @property

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py in __init__(self, entities
, session)
    108         self.session = session
    109         self._polymorphic_adapters = {}
--> 110         self._set_entities(entities)
    111
    112     def _set_entities(self, entities, entity_wrapper=None):

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py in _set_entities(self, ent
ities, entity_wrapper)
    116         self._primary_entity = None
    117         for ent in util.to_list(entities):
--> 118             entity_wrapper(self, ent)
    119
    120         self._set_entity_selectables(self._entities)

C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\query.py in __init__(self, query, c
olumn, namespace)
   3576             raise sa_exc.InvalidRequestError(
   3577                 "SQL expression, column, or mapped entity "
-> 3578                 "expected - got '%r'" % (column, )
   3579             )
   3580         elif not check_column:

InvalidRequestError: SQL expression, column, or mapped entity expected - got '<c
lass '__main__.FD_Group'>'
```

Could help on how to add primary columns in Autobase without adding in the DB directly ?